# OBJ File Stops Being Smooth After Edits In Blender

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, edit-mode, obj

I'm having someone modify a perfectly smooth OBJ file of a can for me (blue). But no matter what settings he uses in Blender, his modified OBJ file of a can (purple) gets sent back to me and renders with much faceting / meshing / paneling.

He is new to Blender and I am completely new to 3D.

[image: OBJ files in Adobe Dimension]

Comment: What program was the original (blue) one made in?

Comment: What happens if you right-click on the purple can and, from the Object Context menu that appears, choose Shade Smooth?

Comment: @Psyonic ... I got the freely-available file from GrabCAD, and do not know enough about 3D to know in what it was made. There are several different version of the file in the download zip, but we have used the OBJ file. I haven't been able to reach the creator of the can. Here is the link: https://grabcad.com/library/aluminum-can-high-detail-16-oz

Comment: The above image is a render in Adobe Dimension. I imported the original GrabCAD OBJ file (blue) into Dimension and then I imported the edited OBJ file (purple) into Dimension as well. This side-by-side then shows what happens after we open the original GrabCAD OBJ file (blue), and then the edited OBJ file (purple). We can't seem to keep the smoothness intact after editing OBJ file (purple) in Blender, saving it as an OBJ file, and then importing it into Dimension.

Comment: @R-800 ... I'll ask him to give it a try in Blender. We'll see if that brings the smoothness back, to then save out as an OBJ file, for me to import into Adobe Dimension. Thanks.

Comment: You say you'll try it, then "save it out as an OBJ." The feature I'm describing will have no bearing on your efforts to save afterwards, because the feature I'm describing only affects the display quality of the object in the 3D View. I ask my quesiton only to rule out the display issue possibility. But maybe you've already ruled it out. If you are trying to export as OBJ, and the problem caries over to other packages, then its more likely that the problem is bad normals, and not display settings. In that case, they would have to be repaired, using the Normals menu (Alt-n) in Edit Mode.

Comment: @Berklie That makes more sense. OBJ format is a mesh format. It consists of nothing more than a bunch of flat faces. This is how Blender is showing it. As R-800 said, use "shade smooth" to make it look smooth. You'll also need to turn on auto-smooth in the normals tab in the Object Data Properties.

Comment: Thank you, both. I'll forward the information to my friend and see if he can get different results. I'll report back after he gets back to me. Thanks!

Comment: What version of Blender are you using? I imported the OBJ into Blender 2.91 and it seems perfectly fine to me...
https://gyazo.com/0206764c09eeba9cc0193cab4b0131e5